# FormApp.GridItem.setRows() producing duplicated columns in the linked Sheet. How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

When `setRows()` run on an existing `GridItem`, the generated `Form GridItem` elements are fine, but the columns in the **linked Sheet** are reproduced in the next columns. The new columns are duplicates, but with a hidden *property* that shows that they belong to the **Form** (so we cannot delete the new columns). What is this *property*? The old columns are no more belong to the **Form**. The old columns may have existing values or previous Form responses.

*How to prevent this?*

The `FormApp` should handles the sheet Ranges properly, by looking for the existing columns and just adds the real new columns with new array of strings.

*How did the Google Forms UI handle this:*
When we use the Forms UI, we can easily add new rows in GridItem, and the link Sheet will be updated without duplicated columns.

Here is the Form to test, and please create a new linked response-Sheet before running the code:

[Copy Sample Form with GAS code](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DTdliGOxA_p0ft_lvmJYAe8y6-vUwtJZ66fnlDyXG8E/copy)

Here is the **GAS** code:

```js
function reGenerateRows1() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  for (const item of form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID)) {
    if (item.getTitle() === 'First Question') {
      item.asGridItem()
      // repopulate from existing rows or from new string array
        .setRows(item.asGridItem().getRows())
      // .setRows(['A','B','C','D','E'])
      // .setRows(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
      // result: Duplicates in destination sheet
      break;
    }
  }
}
function reGenerateRows2() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  for (const item of form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID)) {
    if (item.getTitle() === 'First Question') {
      let grid = item.asGridItem()
      let rows = grid.getRows()
      let columns = grid.getColumns()
      let title = grid.getTitle()
      form.deleteItem(item)
      // recreate GridItem and repopulate
      form.addGridItem().setTitle(title).setRows(rows).setColumns(columns)
      // result: Duplicates in destination sheet
      break;
    }
  }
}
function reGenerateRows3() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  for (const item of form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID)) {
    if (item.getTitle() === 'First Question') {
      let grid = item.asGridItem()
      let rows = grid.getRows()
      let columns = grid.getColumns()
      let id = item.getId()
      // repopulate from id
      form.getItemById(id).asGridItem().setRows(rows).setColumns(columns)
      // result: Duplicates in destination sheet
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edited with screenshots** (I'm new here. Cannot embed image. Only imgur-linked image)

Here is the result of `.setRows(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])`
Original rows are with `'A','B','C'`

[Screenshot of resulting .setRows()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPgRl.png)

Here is what I expect `.setRows()` to do:

[Screenshot of expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8O3S.png)

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you are trying to do, and what the result is, and why its not the desired result, maybe with a screenshot?

Comment: I ran your code and I am able to delete the original columns. It seems that when it regenerates, its the latest ones that are locked. Is that not the same for you?

Comment: Thank for replying. I've added the screenshots. I don't want to delete the original columns. I want them to merge together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Editing Grids in Forms with a linked sheet.

The process of **manually** editing a grid in a form with a linked sheet is as follows:

1. You click the input box for the item.
2. You update the text.
3. The sheet will automatically replace the title of the corresponding column.

However, with Apps Script. The only process available to change a title, is to use the method `.setRows` or `.setColumns`. This behaves very differently from the UI. Esentially, it **replaces** the rows, and so, the linked sheet will generate new columns so as to preserve the previous answers.

It creates new columns because it has no way to know which new title corresponds to the old one.

For example, if you had some rows:

- A
- B
- C

When you get this from Apps Script, you have to first [`getRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#getRows())

```js
const rows = item.getRows()
```

This is returned as a list of **strings**:

```js
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

So here you have already lost some vital information. If the rows were returned as their own type of object with an internal id number or something, so that you could call a hypothetical `setTitle` on the row, then this would be great, however, this is not the case.

If you then change rows to:

```js
const newRows = ['A', 'C', 'B']
```

And then pass it to the form like:

```
item.setRows(newRows)
```

It has no way to know which item corresponds to the other, and so it just regenerates the whole thing.

Again, for it to behave as it does in the UI, the rows and columns would need to be implemented differently. Perhaps as their own class. Maybe `FormGridColumns` and `FormGridRows` or something like that. This ideally would have its own methods, e.g.:

```js
const rows = item.getRows()
rows[0].setTitle('B')
```

This is an example of a way that this could be implemented, but since its not implemented, the only recourse you have is to file a feature request with this template:

> #### [File an Apps Script Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)

#### Possible workaround

Its possible to write your own function to update and merge the columns in the sheet, but it can get complex pretty quickly. It also requires doses of `Utilities.sleep` and `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`, but seems to be reliable in my testing.

For example, I wrote this function that will update and merge rows, but only if the new rows have the same number of elements as the existing rows.

```js
/**
 * Updates a gridItem's column names and merges previous answers
 * into the new columns that are created automatically.
 * @param {GridItem}
 * @param {string}
 * @param {array} - must have same number of rows as gridItem currently has
 */
function updateRows(gridItem, ssID, newRows){
  // Getting basic data from sheet
  const file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sheet = file.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = dataRange.getValues();
  const headers = values.shift()

  // Getting existing title and rows from form
  const itemTitle = gridItem.getTitle()
  const oldRows = gridItem.getRows()

  // Check to make sure newRows is the same length as the current rows
  if (oldRows.length !== newRows.length) {
    throw "new rows and old rows must be same length"
  }

  // Finding which column the old rows are in the spreadsheet
  const oldRowHeaderIndices = getIndicesOfRows(itemTitle, headers, oldRows)

  // Setting the new rows which will autogenerate new columns in the spreadsheet
  gridItem.setRows(newRows)

  // Need to sleep and flush so that the changes have time to propagate
  console.log("sleeping")
  Utilities.sleep(6000) // I found anything less than 6 seconds was unreliable
  console.log("woken up")
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  // Refreshing the data from the sheet
  const updatedDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const updatedValues = updatedDataRange.getValues();
  const updatedHeaders = updatedValues.shift()
  
  // Finding the columns that the new rows are in
  const newRowHeaderIndices = getIndicesOfRows(itemTitle, updatedHeaders, newRows)

  // Copying all the data from old columns to new columns
  for (let i = 0; i != oldRows.length; i++) {

    const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(
      2,
      oldRowHeaderIndices[i] + 1,
      updatedValues.length,
      1
    )

    const destinationRange = sheet.getRange(
      2,
      newRowHeaderIndices[i] + 1,
      updatedValues.length,
      1
    )

    destinationRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues())
  }

  // Deleting old columns (assuming that they are all adjacent to each other)
  sheet.deleteColumns(oldRowHeaderIndices[0] + 1, oldRowHeaderIndices.length)
}

function getIndicesOfRows(itemTitle, headers, rows){
  return rows.map((rowTitle, i) => {
    return headers.findIndex(header => {
        return header === `${itemTitle} [${rowTitle}]`
    })
  })
}
```

#### Usage example

Starting point:

[image]

Then you can call the function like this (adapted from your code):

```js
function test() {
  // Get your form as usual
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  for (const item of form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID)) {
    if (item.getTitle() === 'First Question') {

      const originalRows = item.asGridItem().getRows()
      // ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

      // Here just appending "NEW" to the name to create a new row
      const newRows = originalRows.map(row => "NEW " + row)
      // ['NEW A', 'NEW B', 'NEW C', 'NEW D', 'NEW E', 'NEW F']

      const ssID = form.getDestinationId()

      // Call custom function
      updateRows(item.asGridItem(), ssID, newRows)

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The script takes around 10 seconds to run and will result in:

[image]

#### Conclusion

The proposed function may be quite limited in usage. Though, with enough time, it could probably be adapted to suit most use cases.

Clearly the best thing would be if Google could implement grid rows and grid columns as classes, but that would necessitate a feature request and for Google to accept it if they feel that many people want it.

#### References

- [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thank you very much. Indeed Google needs to update the FormApp API. It should have the API like the updated SpreadsheetApp API which is more advanced in its latest version. Thanks for the proposed function. I will try to implement it if it's possible. But I know that my real form is having more GridItems, and the Rows are growing little by little, and only a few times being changed with constant length to the originals. I accept your answer.

Comment: And I would like to share my current workaround for analyzing the responses using Sheets' formula, as for the current/your workaround is quite hard to implement for many GridItems.

Comment: First image:[This is the response without any workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPgRl.png)  Second image:[This is how to analyze the data: Flatten or unpivot the responses](https://imgur.com/crsWbcz)  The Sheets' formula: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY( TRANSPOSE(ENTRI!A2:A),,9^9))&"|"&ENTRI!B1:J1&"|"&ENTRI!B2:J),"|",FALSE,TRUE), "WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL",0))`

Comment: @zaimuddin nice. Btw, if you do file the feature request, post the url here so that other people can find it if they want it.